# Swift extension with class: how to make a function to return an object's real type?

Tags: swift, class, runtime

I have code like this:

```
class A{}


class B: A{
    var val = 1
}

class C: A{
    var num = 5
}


extension Optional where Wrapped == [B?]{
    var vals: [B]{
        var result = [B]()
        if let arr = self{
            for part in arr{
                if let val = part{
                    result.append(val)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == [C?]{
    var vals: [C]{
        var result = [C]()
        if let arr = self{
            for part in arr{
                if let val = part{
                    result.append(val)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}


var one: [B?]? = [B()]

var two: [C?]? = [C(), nil]



print(one.vals.count)
print(two.vals.count)
```

Here is the optimized one:

Combined into one, for B ( A's subclass ) & C ( A's subclass )

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection{
    var vals: [A]{
        var result = [A]()
        if let arr = self{
            for part in arr{
                if let val = part as? A{
                    result.append(val)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Now question comes,

for case like the follwing,

how to go on the optimization?

```
print(one.vals.first?.val ?? "")
print(two.vals.first?.num ?? "")
```

I guess, I need a function to return an object's real type

> PS: I know , to handle data , struct is perfect with protocol

> While it's a company project, & I'm a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce an extra type variable to say that the extension works on `Optional`s where `Wrapped.Element` is another `Optional` *of any type*. You have to express the "any type" part with another type variable, but you cannot add this type variable in the extension's declaration (though this feature is being [proposed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/25263)), or the property's declaration. What you can do instead, is to make `vals` a function:

```
func vals<T>() -> [T] where Wrapped.Element == T? {
    var result = [T]()
    if let arr = self{
        for part in arr{
            if let val = part{
                result.append(val)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Note that this can be simplified to:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Sequence {
    func vals<T>() -> [T] where Wrapped.Element == T? {
        self?.compactMap { $0 } ?? []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. Another possible approach to keep it as a computed property instead of a generic method is to create an `AnyOptional` protocol with an associatedtype `Wrapped` and conform `Optional` to it. Then you can create a computed property to return an array of its `Wrapped` `Element` `Wrapped` type:

---

```
protocol AnyOptional {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { self }
}

extension AnyOptional where Wrapped: Sequence, Wrapped.Element: AnyOptional {
    var elements: [Wrapped.Element.Wrapped] {
        optional?.compactMap(\.optional) ?? []
    }
}
```

---

```
print(one.elements) // "[B]\n"
print(two.elements) // "[C]\n"

print(one.elements.first?.val ?? "")  // "1\n"
print(two.elements.first?.num ?? "")  // "5\n"
```